# Unable to render flask hello world in subpackage

Tags: python, flask

I cannot seem to be able to replicate any minimal example on the flask documentation page when the web app is a subpackage

```
In [8]: from subpkg.apps.myapp import run_me

In [9]: run_me.main()
 * Running on http://localhost:5050/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2018 22:38:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Folder structure is part of a larger python library. For example the only `.py` files containing code are listed below

```
pkg/
-- setup.py
-- subpkg/
-- __init__.py
-- -- apps/
-- -- __init__.py
-- -- -- myapp/
-- -- -- -- __init__.py
-- -- -- -- run_me.py
-- -- -- -- web/
-- -- -- -- -- views.py
-- -- -- -- -- __init__.py
```

Create the example

```
mkdir pkg; mkdir pkg/subpkg/; mkdir pkg/subpkg/apps; mkdir pkg/subpkg/apps/myapp; mkdir pkg/subpkg/apps/myapp/web
touch pkg/__init__.py; touch pkg/subpkg/__init__.py; touch pkg/subpkg/apps/__init__.py; touch pkg/subpkg/apps/myapp/__init__.py; touch pkg/subpkg/apps/myapp/web/__init__.py; touch pkg/setup.py; touch touch pkg/subpkg/apps/myapp/web/views.py; touch pkg/subpkg/apps/myapp/run_me.py
```

**`pkg/setup.py`**

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
setup(
    name='pkg-myapp',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=['flask==0.11.1'],
    entry_points={'console_scripts': ['pkg-myapp=pkg.apps.myapp.run_me:main',],},
)
```

**`pkg/subpkg/apps/myapp/run_me.py`**

```
from .web import app
def main():
    app.run('localhost', 5050)
```

**`pkg/subpkg/apps/myapp/web/views.py`**

```
from . import app
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return 'hello world'
```

**`pkg/subpkg/apps/myapp/web/__init__.py`**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask('subpkg.apps.myapp.web')
```

## Refs

- http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/organizing.html
- http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/
- https://damyanon.net/post/flask-series-structure/
- [Flask not finding routes in imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874629/flask-not-finding-routes-in-imported-modules)
- [How to run flask app after reorganization as a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071244/how-to-run-flask-app-after-reorganization-as-a-package)

Comment: Did you run the `pkg/subpkg/apps/myapp/web/views.py`? I believe you never import this file so the code is never executed, right?

Comment: I'll just double check my minimal example. I may have just forgotten the import. I'll respond in a moment but I'll be mad if it's that trivial...

Comment: @Sraw I can confirm I hate myself - it was as simple as adding one line `from . import views` ... not sure it there is much point in this thread remaining

Comment: Hum... At least you solve it now :)